# Get ip address my telegram bot is sending messages from

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've made a simple monitoring system in one of my projects: cron task is checking for errors in the data and when it finds one it sends a message to a Telegram chat using one of my bots.

I defined 3 variables in code:

`chatId` - contains id of the chat to send messages to

`token` - bot's security token

`instanceId` - id of my application instance (hostname of the VM for exactly this instance)

So bot defined by the *token* sends to the chat defined by the *chatId* messages containing the description of a problem and *instanceId* to distinguish the source of the message.

Someone of our team members has copied the project or part of it, including that part with monitoring. And deployed it somewhere. How I know it? My chat is full of alerts! My bot is sending it endlessly from somewhere and I see that *instanceId* is equals to one of my id used in project before, but its coming not from that project. Message is something like:

```
There is a problem with the data:

Database: db123, TableName: Table123, RowId: UUID123

Instance id: instance123.domain.com
```

But I know that *instance123.domain.com* has no such row in that table, moreover I already shut it down completely.

So the question is how do I know where those messages come from if no one of our team admits it was him/her?
I want to know if there any feature on the Telegram side (API method, admin panel) that makes it possible to know where those bot API calls are coming from.

Comment: Could you please add the programming language tag? Did you code the bot in PHP, Python or something else?

Comment: It's in PHP but it makes no difference cause it's not about PHP, it's about Telegram API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue, using a simple Telegram bot (api call) to show the IP of each device the script has running.

While the Telegram bot doensn't provide such info, you can use [php](/questions/tagged/php) to gather the desired info, the following code shows the **hostname** and **ip address**:

```php
<?php

    $hostname = gethostname();
    $local_ip = getHostByName($hostname);

    $message = <<<EOL
There is a problem with the data:

Database: db123, TableName: Table123, RowId: UUID123

Device info:
Hostname: ${hostname}
IP: ${local_ip}
Instance id: instance123.domain.com

EOL;

// Send $message
// ...
```

With wil produce :

```
There is a problem with the data:

Database: db123, TableName: Table123, RowId: UUID123

Device info:
Hostname: my-pc-hostname
IP: 192.168.2.9
Instance id: instance123.domain.com
```

Comment: Nice solution to use in future projects. But someone already bothering me with alerts I'm not interested in.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I want to know if there any feature on the Telegram side (API method, admin panel) that makes it possible to know where those bot API calls are coming from.

Comment: @IvanA.Malich, as described in my answer, there isn't a way to distinguish different bot cals. Please consider upvoting my answer, or clarifying the question.